# Why REP can be added to any String Data Transfer except LODS?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

```
REP STOSB (STOSW or STOSD )
REP MOVSB
REP INSB
REP OUTSB
```

Those string data transfer are allowed, but my course material says `REP LODSB` is not?

Comment: Why would you want to `LODS` bytes in a row overwriting previously loaded stuff without even looking into it?

Comment: I don't know if the CPUs actively detect REP LODSB and trap; you'd have to check the reference manuals.   If I were a chip designer, I wouldn't bother; as Roman points it, it would (if executed) uselessly load the AL/AX/EAX/RAX with data from successive memory locations, but that's just a complicated NOP and wasting transistors to detect silly things in program isn't a good use of chip real estate (or more important, extra heat).  So, REP LODSB might actually be legal, but as Roman pointed it, it is pretty useless.

Comment: To those who dinged this question:  I think it perfectly reasonable that this guy asked.  Weren't you a newbie at one time in your life?

Comment: Loading data with out using it, it's a good reason.Asking experts always gives a nice result that's why I am asking thank you.

Comment: I actually think that `rep lodsb` is legal and valid instruction. A quick googling http://books.google.com.ua/books?id=F5MhjlEnnO0C&pg=PA649&lpg=PA649&dq=rep+lodsb&source=bl&ots=WBwQNZQs7m&sig=VN74Vqe7qX5I-L1yH8irRWKY_PE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=LIiCUb_uBI-VswaXs4HYDQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=rep%20lodsb&f=false + http://vitaly_filatov.tripod.com/ng/asm/asm_000.71.html makes me even more sure. The second links also contains the answer to the question. This way of asking does not show any research effort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `rep lodsb`, `rep lodsw`, `rep lodsd` and `rep lodsq` instructions are all perfectly valid. There's almost never a use for them though, as you can't do anything with the data you've loaded.

The only case I can think of where they might be useful is for areas of memory mapped IO with read side-effects (which is extremely rare).

Comment: Could also be used to force the virtual memory to be paged in from disk.

Comment: @stark True, but given a page size of 4096, 4095 iterations would be wasted, since the first one causes the page to be brought in, and the rest will find that it's already there...

Comment: Thanks Brendan for the useful answer, the thing is I am student and in the course copybook written `REP Added to any string data transfer except LODS` and I thought that it's not make sense because I tested it on `emu8086` it was working fine.

I think I will discuss this matter with my lecturer. again thanks